# Custom recurring notifications not being set from firebase console

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send customs notifications every 3 days at 9.00 pm according to recipient time zone. But publishing or saving the notification causes an error by saying

> There was an error saving the campaign.

Which is pretty vague.

Note that this error does not occur when I set time to "now" instead.

Comment: how you solve this ?

Comment: @VLeonovs I couldn't and stopped working on it. If you do find a solution do mention that as answer. it will helpful for the community.

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have 10 recurring notifications already set up. Please check and see. You can only have 10 recurring notifications at any one time.

Answer (score 0):

I think this bug occurs when you select "Recipient time zone".

When I choose a different time zone I'm able to save the campaign. Then I just edit the message and set it back to the recipient's time zone. Works for me

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs because some recipient time zones are ahead of your own. So you have to set the start date 1 or 2 days ahead of your own time, it should save then.